# Evaluate $\int_{-n}^{n} (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am not sure how to solve this.

I tried checking it for odd/even function but we don't have $\lfloor -x \rfloor=-\lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: $(-1)^{\lfloor (-x)\rfloor}=-(-1)^{\lfloor (x)\rfloor}$

Comment: @CooperCape How ?

Comment: Draw out the graph and there is an obvious pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us set the function
$$f(x) = (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$
A common equivalence regarding the floor function is
$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$} \\ -1 & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$} \end{cases}$$
Considering when $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$,
$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = -1$$
$$\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\lfloor x \rfloor - 1$$
If we now consider $f(-x)$,
$$f(-x) = (-1)^{\lfloor -x \rfloor} = (-1)^{-\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} = \frac{1}{-1 \cdot (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}} = -(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} = -f(x)$$
Since this is true for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and discontinuities of measure zero do not affect Riemann integration, we can treat this as an odd function. This means that
$$\int_{-n}^n (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} {\rm d}x = 0$$
for $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The graph of $(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ consists of alternating segments of length $1$ with values $+1$ and $-1$.  The integral over a period, which is length $2$, is zero.  Therefore the integral over any interval of length an even integer is zero.  Your interval has length $2n$